# Strange query with some if conditions

Tags: mysql

Fellow programmers,

I got a table where i have the following columns :

```
[tablename - usertimes]
id - int(11)
user_id - int(11)
time - timestamp
deleted - tinyint(1)
```

Imagine i have the following rows :

```
[id] [user_id]      [time]       [deleted]
------------------------------------------
 1       1     2013-02-25 16:40     0
 2       1     2013-02-25 14:40     0
 3       1     2013-02-25 11:20     1
 4       1     2013-02-26 11:20     1
 5       2     2013-02-23 16:40     0
 6       2     2013-02-25 16:40     0
```

Now i need to group by `date(`time`)`, `user_id` where `min(`time`)` i have the minimum time where deleted is not false. BUT!!! If the only row for that date has deleted=true, then it has to return that. so it has to return the following rows :

```
[id] [user_id]      [time]       [deleted]
------------------------------------------
 2       1     2013-02-25 14:40     0
 4       1     2013-02-26 11:20     1
 5       2     2013-02-23 16:40     0
 6       2     2013-02-25 16:40     0
```

What would be the best approach for this? Should i just get all rows and check them in my code? I believe that a query must be possible for this but i can't wrap my head around it.

**EDIT:**

Can somebody please play with this fiddle? :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f91a

It has the table contents and the desired output commented.

**EDIT2:**

This is the output according to this fiddle : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3808b/1

```
| ID | USER_ID | DELETED |             TIME |
---------------------------------------------
|  1 |       1 |       0 | 2013-02-25 14:40 |
|  4 |       1 |       1 | 2013-02-26 11:20 |
|  5 |       2 |       0 | 2013-02-23 16:40 |
|  6 |       2 |       0 | 2013-02-25 16:40 |
```

This is really close to what i want to achieve. Because what i want to achieve is this result  ***notice the first id*** :

```
| ID | USER_ID | DELETED |             TIME |
---------------------------------------------
|  2 |       1 |       0 | 2013-02-25 14:40 |
|  4 |       1 |       1 | 2013-02-26 11:20 |
|  5 |       2 |       0 | 2013-02-23 16:40 |
|  6 |       2 |       0 | 2013-02-25 16:40 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm not sure what the heck you are doing, but this query gives you your result

```
select ut.*
from usertimes ut
join (
select user_id,deleted, min(time) as time
from usertimes
group by date(time), user_id, deleted
) a on a.user_id = ut.user_id and a.time = ut.time
group by ut.user_id, date(ut.time)
order by ut.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e23c44/1):

```
(
SELECT id,user_id,deleted,min(time) as TIME
FROM usertimes
WHERE deleted=0
GROUP BY date(time), user_id
)
UNION
(
SELECT id,user_id,deleted,time FROM(
SELECT *,COUNT(user_id) as cnt_user_id 
FROM usertimes GROUP BY user_id,date(time) 
)a
WHERE a.deleted=1 and a.cnt_user_id =1  
)ORDER BY user_id
```

Comment: That query almost returns the right result except for the id : 1, which has to be id : 2, because it is the earliest time on that date for that user.

Comment: I edited my answer, can you please change your query to my needs?

Comment: working on it.. This gets really interesting..thanks for pointing this:)